# Google Sheets double Data Validation Script for one Column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to validate content and restrict input in the cells of one row in Google Sheets using a Script. Cells have to be Numbers between 100000 and 999999 and content can't be duplicated. If the input is duplicated, a message will tell the user of the duplicate. If the number is not six digits as per the rule the user will be notified with a message.

I tried Google's Data Validation but, I'm restricted to only one Custom command (as far as I know). Also tried Conditional Formatting but, did not get the result I wanted with the notification to the user, I only get a highlight on the duplicated cell. And finally a combination of the two, which could work, but it is not my desired result.

```
function validateMySpreadsheet() {
// Rule for the cells to be a number between 100000 and 999999.
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A2:A1000');
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
     .requireNumberBetween(100000, 999999)
     .setAllowInvalid(false)
     .setHelpText('Enter a number between 100-000 and 999-999.')
     .build();
  // Rule to check for duplicates and deny input if TRUE
  var duplicate = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
  //Code missing HERE to check for duplicates in "cell"
     .setAllowInvalid(false)
     .setHelpText('Number entered already exists.')
     .build();
  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
  cell.setDataValidation(duplicate);
}
```

The expected result will be to input ID number in any cell in this row and get a notification if the number doesn't fall within the rule (this part of the code works and the result is as expected). Get notification also when the ID already exists on the specified cell range (some code missing on this second part causing problems).